# SELECT, Count & Insert in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I suspect it is.

I'm trying to gather some very basic statistics, so I have a'tracker' table that stores info on an ongoing basis, like so;

ID, IP, itemid

Each time an item is viewed, the visitors IP address and the Item ID are logged.

On a daily basis, I'd like to summarize this data and insert it into another table, like so;

ID, itemid, views

Now, the 'views' element I want to be unique - so ignoring any duplicate IP addresses (counting them only once).

I know I could simply loop through them all and do it that way, but is it possible to do the entire process with just a single query?

I'm using MySQL

Comment: Why do you have a surrogate primary key in the tracker table?

Comment: @Jack - ID is the unique, auto-incrementing primary key for an indidivual record. The others will not be unique

Comment: Yes, I know what it does; the question is why you have it :)

Comment: Actually, thats a good question - and to be honest, I'm not sure. I guess I was always taught that every table needed such a thing. I've never questioned it until now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group the `tracker` table by `itemid`, the number of distinct IP addresses should be the number of views you want:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (itemid, views)
SELECT itemid, COUNT(DISTINCT IP)
FROM tracker
GROUP BY itemid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
insert into newtable(itemid,views) 
select itemid,count(*) 
from (
select itemid 
from tracker 
group by itemid,ip
) 
as a 
group by a.itemid.
```

Comment: If you write your code cleaner like Jack did may be chances of getting upvotes are higher

Answer (score 1):

In other RDBMS it possible on this manner:

```
    insert into othertable (field_views, field_itemid)
    select count(distinct t.views), t.itemid from tracker
    group by t.itemid
```

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Note, this solution implies presence autoincrement in othertable.id